# Kotlin RecyclerView with Multiple ViewHolders inside BottomSheet

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm having troubles trying to display a recycler which contains more than 1 ViewHolder, i was testing and sending a custom List which contains only data to display a list of the 1st ViewType.

> payments.add(Purchase(0,R.drawable.ic_cart,"",""))
>       payments.add(Purchase(0,R.drawable.ic_favorite,"",""))
>       payments.add(Purchase(0,R.drawable.ic_arrow_back,"",""))

This is the BottomSheetClass

```
class PaymentStepsFragment : SuperBottomSheetFragment() {

val payments = ArrayList<Any>()

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_steps_payment, container, false)
}

private fun RecyclerAnimator(recyclerView: RecyclerView, adapter: PurchaseViewAdapter) {
    val itemAnimator = DefaultItemAnimator()
    itemAnimator.addDuration = 1000
    itemAnimator.removeDuration = 1000
    recyclerView.itemAnimator = itemAnimator
    recyclerView.adapter = adapter
    recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    payments.add(Purchase(0,R.drawable.ic_cart,"",""))
    payments.add(Purchase(0,R.drawable.ic_favorite,"",""))
    payments.add(Purchase(0,R.drawable.ic_arrow_back,"",""))
    val recycler = view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.payment_rv)
    val adapter = PurchaseViewAdapter(payments, context!!)
    RecyclerAnimator(recycler, adapter)
}

override fun getCornerRadius() = context!!.resources.getDimension(R.dimen.sheet_rounded_corner)

override fun getStatusBarColor() = Color.RED
```

}

and my RecyclerViewAdapter.

```
constructor(list: List<Any>, context: Context) : this() {
        this.list = list
        this.context = context
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    return when(viewType){
        0 -> {
            context = parent.context
            val menuItemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.fragment_card_payment, parent, false)
            PaymentViewHolder(menuItemLayoutView)
        }
        else -> {
            context = parent.context
            val menuItemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.fragment_card_payment, parent, false)
            PaymentViewHolder(menuItemLayoutView)
        }
    }
}

override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
    val data = list?.get(position) as Purchase
    return data.type
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    when(holder.itemViewType){
        0 -> {
            val holder_payment = holder as PaymentViewHolder
            val menuItem = list!![position] as Purchase
            holder_payment.paymentTimeline.marker = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context!!,menuItem.resource)
        }
        else -> {
            val holder_payment = holder as PaymentViewHolder
            val menuItem = list!![position] as Purchase
            holder_payment.paymentTimeline.marker = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context!!,menuItem.resource)
        }
    }
}
```

However when I send the information to be displayed, it always return the list empty, I don't know where is the problem, the data it's seems to be sent nicely.

And the constructor of the RecyclerViewAdapter prints the List obtained, but that list won't display the DesiredViewHolders to be inflated in the RecyclerView...

[image: Empty RecyclerList in BottomViewFragment]

As requested I added the Layout where I call the RecyclerView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/view_bottom_sheet_attributes"
        tools:background="@color/colorWhite">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/text_attributes_heading"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="12dp"
            android:text="TEMPORAL"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

    <View
            android:layout_width="0sp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/colorDivider"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/text_attributes_heading"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/image_toggle"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_expand_less_black_24dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/text_attributes_heading"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/text_attributes_heading"/>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/payment_rv"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/text_attributes_heading"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/button_apply">

    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

    <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/colorDivider"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/payment_rv"/>

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:id="@+id/button_apply"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="@string/purchase"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button"
            android:insetTop="0dp"
            android:insetBottom="0dp"
            app:cornerRadius="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/payment_rv"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Also the type of the ViewHolder it seems that don't reach the override function...

Comment: Maybe there´s a problem with `holder.itemViewType` in `onBindViewHolder`, did you put a breakpoint inside `onBindViewHolder`

Comment: Check inside `Purchase` if type is ok

Comment: Check your layout if you missed setting `Match_Parent` height `ConstrintLayout`  
 constraint for `RecyclerView`

Comment: I will update the question with the layout of the RecyclerView and the value holder.itemViewType

Comment: In the layout, test remove the last two views,  `<View` and `button_apply` see what happens. Also you have the [Layout inspector](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/layout-inspector) to work with and investigate your Layout

Comment: Erik you have all the reason, it looks like is a layout problem, but it's weird i think that the constraint_align can resolve those issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your layout XML it looks like the `RecyclerView` view is hidden by other views

Comment: That was the problem, thanks! Im gonna see how to manage the layout to handle the other components :)